# Hiding table border in iTextSharp

Tags: c#, .net, itext

How can i hide the table border using iTextSharp. I am using following code to generate a file:

```
var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 25, 25);

// Create a new PdfWriter object, specifying the output stream
var output = new MemoryStream();
var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);

document.Open();
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
var bodyFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10, Font.NORMAL);
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Header spanning 3 columns"));
cell.Colspan = 3;
cell.HorizontalAlignment = 1; //0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right
table.AddCell(cell);
Font arial = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 6, BaseColor.BLUE);
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Font test is here ", arial));
cell.PaddingLeft = 5f;
cell.Colspan = 1;
table.AddCell(cell);
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("XYX"));
cell.Colspan = 2;
table.AddCell(cell);
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Hello World"));
cell.PaddingLeft = 5f;
cell.Colspan = 1;
table.AddCell(cell);
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("XYX"));
cell.Colspan = 2;
table.AddCell(cell);



table.SpacingBefore = 5f;
document.Add(table);
document.Close();

Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=Receipt-test.pdf");
Response.BinaryWrite(output.ToArray());
```

Do I need to specify no borders for individual cells or I can specify no borders for table itself.

Thank you

Comment: Maybe it's time to accept one of the answers that were presented.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Although I upvoted the answer by Martijn, I want to add a clarification.

Only cells have borders in iText; tables don't have a border. Martijn's suggestion to set the border of the default cell to `NO_BORDER` is correct:

```
table.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
```

But it won't work for the code snippet provided in the question. The properties of the default cell are only used if iText needs to create a `PdfPCell` instance implicitly (for instance: if you use the `addCell()` method passing a `Phrase` as parameter).

In the code snippet provided by @Brown_Dynamite, the `PdfPCell` objects are created explicitly. This means that you need to set the border of each of these cells to `NO_BORDER`.

Usually, I write a factory class to create cells. That way, I can significantly reduce the amount of code in the class that creates the table.

Comment: Thanks @Bruno, I was just trying to figure out yesterday why this wasn't working as I expected! I was going to crack the source today.

Comment: Could you provide us with a snippet for this factory class.

Comment: @Dr.MAF What a strange question. Every one writes such a factory class in his or her own way. If you search the official web site for `CreateCell()`, you'll find a couple of examples: http://itextpdf.com/search/node/createCell (this isn't iText-related; it's a standard practice used by people who have learned how to write code).

Answer (score 11):

This should do the trick:

```
table.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
```

or

```
table.borderwidth= 0;
```

Comment: Thank you reply. I have tried both of these option and they are not working. I think the reason given by Bruno Lowagie makes sense

Comment: there is no borderwidth property of the table object

Answer (score 11):

First we can set all cell borders as 0 and After assigning all cell to table we can use the following code for for only pdfptable outer border.

```
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
        cell.AddElement(t);
        cell.BorderWidthBottom=1f;
        cell.BorderWidthLeft=1f;
        cell.BorderWidthTop=1f;
        cell.BorderWidthRight = 1f;
        PdfPTable t1 = new PdfPTable(1);
        t1.AddCell(cell);
```

Here we can add table to one cell and can set border and again add that cell to another table and we can use as per our requirement.

Answer (score 6):

If your PdfPTable is nested within another PdfPTable, the nested table will show table borders. The only way to get rid of the table borders is to put the nested PdfPTable into a PdfPCell of the main PdfPTable and set the border width of that cell to 0.

```
iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPTable table = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPTable(1); //<-- Main table
table.TotalWidth = 540f;
table.LockedWidth = true;
float[] widths = new float[] { 540f };
table.SetWidths(widths);
table.HorizontalAlignment = 1; //0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right
table.SpacingAfter = 10;

PdfPTable bodyTable = new PdfPTable(1); //<--Nested Table
bodyTable.TotalWidth = 540f;
bodyTable.LockedWidth = true;
float[] bodyWidths = new float[] { 540f };
bodyTable.SetWidths(bodyWidths);
bodyTable.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
bodyTable.SpacingAfter = 10;
bodyTable.DefaultCell.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.NO_BORDER;

var para1 = new Paragraph("This is a long paragraph", blackNormal);
para1.SetLeading(3f, 1f);
PdfPCell bodyCell1 = new PdfPCell();
bodyCell1.AddElement(para1);
bodyCell1.Border = 0;
bodyTable.AddCell(bodyCell1);

iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell cellBody = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell(bodyTable);
cellBody.BorderWidth = 0; //<--- This is what sets the border for the nested table
table.AddCell(cellBody);
```

Took me a long time to figure this out. It works for me now.

Answer (score 3):

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(4);
table.TotalWidth = 400f;
table.LockedWidth = true;
PdfPCell header = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Header"));
header.Colspan = 4;
table.AddCell(header);
table.AddCell("Cell 1");
table.AddCell("Cell 2");
table.AddCell("Cell 3");
table.AddCell("Cell 4");
PdfPTable nested = new PdfPTable(1);
nested.AddCell("Nested Row 1");
nested.AddCell("Nested Row 2");
nested.AddCell("Nested Row 3");
PdfPCell nesthousing = new PdfPCell(nested);
nesthousing.Padding = 0f;
table.AddCell(nesthousing);
PdfPCell bottom = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("bottom"));
bottom.Colspan = 3;
table.AddCell(bottom);
doc.Add(table);
```

---

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
table.TotalWidth = 144f;
table.LockedWidth = true;
table.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
PdfPCell left = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Rotated"));
left.Rotation = 90;
table.AddCell(left);
PdfPCell middle = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Rotated"));
middle.Rotation = -90;
table.AddCell(middle);
table.AddCell("Not Rotated");
doc.Add(table);
```

Check [this link](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/86/iTextSharp-Introducing-Tables) pls

Comment: Please add details on your code and provide a summary of the link you provide.

Answer (score 2):

try this code

```
 yourtable.DefaultCell.Border = 0;
```

Comment: this option not working.