# How to set only vertical line of a table in pdf using itext sharp?

Tags: c#, itext

I have a table with vertical and horizontal lines. But I do not want horizontal line.I want only Vertical lines.How can I set it. My expected o/p is

My Table code

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(5);
table.TotalWidth = 510f;//table size
table.LockedWidth = true;
table.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
table.SpacingBefore = 10f;//both are used to mention the space from heading


table.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
table.AddCell(new Phrase(new Phrase("    SL.NO", font1)));

table.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
table.AddCell(new Phrase(new Phrase("   SUBJECTS", font1)));

table.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
table.AddCell(new Phrase(new Phrase("   MARKS", font1)));

table.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
table.AddCell(new Phrase(new Phrase("   MAX MARK", font1)));

table.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
table.AddCell(new Phrase(new Phrase("   CLASS AVG", font1)));

Doc.Add(table);
```

ex:

[image]

Anybody please help

Comment: @Bruno Lowegi.. I hope you can help me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change the borders of the cells so that they only show the vertical lines. How to do this, depends on how you add the cells to the table.

These are the two approaches:

**1. You create PdfPCell objects explicitly:**

PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
cell.AddElement(new Paragraph("my content"));
cell.Border = PdfPCell.LEFT;
table.AddCell(cell);

In this case, only the *left* border of the cell will be shown. For the last cell in the row you should also add the right border:

cell.Border = PdfPCell.LEFT | PdfPCell.RIGHT;

**2. You create PdfPCell objects implicitly:**

In this case, you don't create a `PdfPCell` object yourself, you let iTextSharp create the cells. These cells will copy the properties of the `DefaultCell` that is defined at the level of the `PdfPTable`, so you need to change this:

```
table.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.LEFT | Rectangle.RIGHT;
table.addCell("cell 1");
table.addCell("cell 2");
table.addCell("cell 3");
```

Now all the cells won't have a top or bottom border, only a left and right border. You'll be drawing some extra lines, but nobody will notice as the lines coincide.

See also [Hiding table border in iTextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980291/hiding-table-border-in-itextsharp)

For instance:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(5);
table.TotalWidth = 510f;//table size
table.LockedWidth = true;
table.SpacingBefore = 10f;//both are used to mention the space from heading
table.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
table.DefaultCell.Border = PdfPCell.LEFT | PdfPCell.RIGHT;
table.AddCell(new Phrase("    SL.NO", font1));
table.AddCell(new Phrase("   SUBJECTS", font1));
table.AddCell(new Phrase("   MARKS", font1));
table.AddCell(new Phrase("   MAX MARK", font1));
table.AddCell(new Phrase("   CLASS AVG", font1));
Doc.Add(table);
```

There is no need to define the properties of the `DefaultCell` so many times. There is no need to nest `Phrase` constructors like this: `new Phrase(new Phrase("content"))`.

Comment: Kindly find my edited question. This is the way I am creating table. How can I do the same in it??

Comment: It is 7:42 in New York, so it is morning!

Comment: ooohh here 05:13 pm (India)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90611/discussion-between-semil-sebastian-and-bruno-lowagie).

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Bruno didn't helped me but I got an idea maybe because that's in the year 2015 but here's what I did.
I declare a table

```
PdfPTable table2 = new PdfPTable(8);
```

defines the width..

```
table2.WidthPercentage = 100;
```

And finaly put only the border that I liked

```
table2.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.RIGHT_BORDER;
table2.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.LEFT_BORDER;
```

and of course if you want to use it to display.

```
table2.AddCell(new Phrase("Total Amount", ftxt));
table2.AddCell(new Phrase("Another text", ftxt));
```

and of course adding it to the pdf.

```
doc.Add(table2);
```

It seems that iTextSharp has built-in column/rows like cell type if you didn't specify it.